# joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Simple question but I am confused about the query, I have three tables

First table:  projects

```
proj_id      project_cost     project_description
-------     ------------     -------------------
1              123.45          construction plan A
2              222.22          construction plan B
3              333.33          construction plan c
4              444.44          construction plan D
5              555.55          construction plan E
```

Second table:  project_estimates

```
est_id      proj_id        fy           Q1          Q2      Q3     Q4 
-------     -------     ---------      -----      ------   -----  -------
1            2          2015-16         12          11       15    19
2            3          2015-16         11          22       45    23
3            4          2015-16         31          32       36    56
4            1          2015-16         51          34       45    78
5            5          2015-16         33          44       59    98
```

Third table:  project_expenditure:

```
exp_id      proj_id        fy           Q1          Q2      Q3     Q4 
-------     -------     ---------      -----      ------   -----  -------
1              3          2015-16        10         12       41     15
2              5          2015-16        31         24       39     70
```

Now I would like to join these tables to get an output like:

Project details for 2015-16

```
proj_id            Proposed                      expenditure
---------    -----------------------       --------------------- 
              Q1     Q2     Q3    Q4       Q1     Q2    Q3    Q4
----------------------------------------------------------------
1            51      34     45    78      NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL
2            12      11     15    19      NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL
3            11      22     45    23       10    12     41     15
4            31      32     36    56      NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL
5            33      44     59    98       31    24     39     70
```

further, there are other entries in table two and table three for financial 2015-16, I need only project_id which has project estimates in 2015-16 but I want the columns values from project_expenditure even if entries are not made. I tried with `a.proj_id=b.proj_id` and `a.proj_id=c.proj_id(+)` but it is not giving the expected output. Anything else that can be put in scope to get the result.

Comment: Could you provide your SQL statement and results of its execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I couldn't test this atm but I would do something like this:

```
SELECT
    proj_id,
    project_estimates.Q1,
    project_estimates.Q2,
    project_estimates.Q3,
    project_estimates.Q4,
    project_expenditure.Q1,
    project_expenditure.Q2,
    project_expenditure.Q3,
    project_expenditure.Q4
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN project_estimates ON (project_estimates.proj_id = projects.proj_id)
LEFT JOIN project_expenditure ON (project_expenditure.proj_id = projects.proj_id)
WHERE projects.proj_id IN (
    (SELECT proj_id FROM project_estimates WHERE (project_estimates.fy = '2015-16'))
    UNION
    (SELECT proj_id FROM project_expenditure WHERE (project_expenditure.fy = '2015-16'))
GROUP BY proj_id
)
ORDER BY proj_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be first an INNER join as you want only projects with estimates in 2015-16 and then a LEFT join as you want it to get populated by NULL if the entry is not there :

```
SELECT prj.proj_id,
       prj_est.Q1,
       prj_est.Q2,
       prj_est.Q3,
       prj_est.Q4,
       prj_exp.Q1,
       prj_exp.Q2,
       prj_exp.Q3,
       prj_exp.Q4
  FROM projects AS prj
       INNER JOIN project_estimates AS prj_est ON prj.proj_id = prj_est.proj_id
                                                  AND prj_est.fy = '2015-16'
       LEFT JOIN project_expenditure AS prj_exp ON prj.proj_id = prj_exp.proj_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using LEFT JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT projects.proj_id,
       project_estimates.Q1,
       project_estimates.Q2,
       project_estimates.Q3,
       project_estimates.Q4,
       project_expenditure.Q1,
       project_expenditure.Q2,
       project_expenditure.Q3,
       project_expenditure.Q4
FROM  projects
LEFT JOIN project_estimates ON (project_estimates.proj_id = projects.proj_id)
LEFT JOIN project_expenditure ON (project_expenditure.proj_id  = projects.proj_id)
ORDER BY projects.proj_id
```

If I understood correctly, it will achieve your necessity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're not getting the expected output, unless it's because you've not put in the join on the ext.fy = exp.fy?

This works for me:

```
with          projects as (select 1 proj_id, 123.45 project_cost, 'construction plan A' project_description from dual union all
                           select 2 proj_id, 222.22 project_cost, 'construction plan B' project_description from dual union all
                           select 3 proj_id, 333.33 project_cost, 'construction plan C' project_description from dual union all
                           select 4 proj_id, 444.44 project_cost, 'construction plan D' project_description from dual union all
                           select 5 proj_id, 555.55 project_cost, 'construction plan E' project_description from dual),
     project_estimates as (select 1 est_id, 2 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 12 q1, 11 q2, 15 q3, 19 q4 from dual union all
                           select 2 est_id, 3 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 11 q1, 22 q2, 45 q3, 23 q4 from dual union all
                           select 3 est_id, 4 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 31 q1, 32 q2, 36 q3, 59 q4 from dual union all
                           select 4 est_id, 1 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 51 q1, 34 q2, 34 q3, 78 q4 from dual union all
                           select 5 est_id, 5 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 33 q1, 44 q2, 44 q3, 98 q4 from dual union all
                           select 6 est_id, 1 proj_id, '2016-17' fy, 33 q1, 44 q2, 44 q3, 98 q4 from dual),
  project_expenditures as (select 1 exp_id, 3 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 10 q1, 12 q2, 41 q3, 15 q4 from dual union all
                           select 2 exp_id, 5 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 31 q1, 24 q2, 39 q3, 70 q4 from dual)
--end of mimicking your tables; see the query below:
select est.fy,
       prj.proj_id,
       est.q1 proposed_q1,
       est.q2 proposed_q2,
       est.q3 proposed_q3,
       est.q4 proposed_q4,
       exp.q1 expenditure_q1,
       exp.q2 expenditure_q2,
       exp.q3 expenditure_q3,
       exp.q4 expenditure_q4
from   projects prj
       left outer join project_estimates est on (prj.proj_id = est.proj_id)
       left outer join project_expenditures exp on (prj.proj_id = exp.proj_id and est.fy = exp.fy)
order by fy, proj_id;

FY         PROJ_ID PROPOSED_Q1 PROPOSED_Q2 PROPOSED_Q3 PROPOSED_Q4 EXPENDITURE_Q1 EXPENDITURE_Q2 EXPENDITURE_Q3 EXPENDITURE_Q4
------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
2015-16          1          51          34          34          78                                                            
2015-16          2          12          11          15          19                                                            
2015-16          3          11          22          45          23             10             12             41             15
2015-16          4          31          32          36          59                                                            
2015-16          5          33          44          44          98             31             24             39             70
2016-17          1          33          44          44          98
```

If you could also have expenditures without estimates, then this ought to do the trick:

```
with          projects as (select 1 proj_id, 123.45 project_cost, 'construction plan A' project_description from dual union all
                           select 2 proj_id, 222.22 project_cost, 'construction plan B' project_description from dual union all
                           select 3 proj_id, 333.33 project_cost, 'construction plan C' project_description from dual union all
                           select 4 proj_id, 444.44 project_cost, 'construction plan D' project_description from dual union all
                           select 5 proj_id, 555.55 project_cost, 'construction plan E' project_description from dual),
     project_estimates as (select 1 est_id, 2 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 12 q1, 11 q2, 15 q3, 19 q4 from dual union all
                           select 2 est_id, 3 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 11 q1, 22 q2, 45 q3, 23 q4 from dual union all
                           select 3 est_id, 4 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 31 q1, 32 q2, 36 q3, 59 q4 from dual union all
                           select 4 est_id, 1 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 51 q1, 34 q2, 34 q3, 78 q4 from dual union all
                           select 5 est_id, 5 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 33 q1, 44 q2, 44 q3, 98 q4 from dual union all
                           select 6 est_id, 1 proj_id, '2016-17' fy, 33 q1, 44 q2, 44 q3, 98 q4 from dual),
  project_expenditures as (select 1 exp_id, 3 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 10 q1, 12 q2, 41 q3, 15 q4 from dual union all
                           select 2 exp_id, 5 proj_id, '2015-16' fy, 31 q1, 24 q2, 39 q3, 70 q4 from dual union all
                           select 3 exp_id, 4 proj_id, '2016-17' fy, 31 q1, 24 q2, 39 q3, 70 q4 from dual)
--end of mimicking your tables; see the query below:
select coalesce(exp.fy, est.fy) fy,
       coalesce(exp.proj_id, est.proj_id, prj.proj_id) proj_id,
       est.q1 proposed_q1,
       est.q2 proposed_q2,
       est.q3 proposed_q3,
       est.q4 proposed_q4,
       exp.q1 expenditure_q1,
       exp.q2 expenditure_q2,
       exp.q3 expenditure_q3,
       exp.q4 expenditure_q4
from   projects prj
       left outer join project_estimates est on (prj.proj_id = est.proj_id)
       full outer join project_expenditures exp on (prj.proj_id = exp.proj_id and est.fy = exp.fy)
order by fy, proj_id;

FY         PROJ_ID PROPOSED_Q1 PROPOSED_Q2 PROPOSED_Q3 PROPOSED_Q4 EXPENDITURE_Q1 EXPENDITURE_Q2 EXPENDITURE_Q3 EXPENDITURE_Q4
------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
2015-16          1          51          34          34          78                                                            
2015-16          2          12          11          15          19                                                            
2015-16          3          11          22          45          23             10             12             41             15
2015-16          4          31          32          36          59                                                            
2015-16          5          33          44          44          98             31             24             39             70
2016-17          1          33          44          44          98                                                            
2016-17          4                                                             31             24             39             70
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.proj_id, pes.Q1, pes.Q2, pes.Q3, pes.Q4, pe.Q1, pe.Q2, pe.Q3, pe.Q4
FROM projects AS p
JOIN project_estimates AS pes ON p.proj_id = pes.proj_id AND pes.fy = '2015-16'
LEFT JOIN project_expenditure AS pe ON p.proj_id = pe.proj_id AND pe.fy = '2015-16'
ORDER BY p.proj_id
```

This will not get you the headlines over the Q1-Q4 rows, but it will give the data output.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT est.proj_id, 
       est.Q1, est.Q2, est.Q3, est.Q4, 
       exp.Q1, exp.Q2, exp.Q3, exp.Q4
  FROM project_estimates AS est 
  LEFT JOIN project_expenditure AS exp 
    ON exp.proj_id = est.proj_id 
   AND est.fy = '2015-16'
 ORDER BY est.proj_id
```