# i really need help again in this joining multiple table

Tags: sql, join

i got 3 tables..

tableA

```
    id     name    amount
---------------------------
    1      xxx     1000.00
    2      yyy      500.00
```

tableB

```
    idkey   project   alloted    
--------------------------------------
    1        xxx       500.00
    1        xxx       500.00 
    2       yyy1       250.00
    2       yyy2       250.00
```

tableC

```
   idkey  Proj   item      cost
 -----------------------------
    1      xxx   hammer    500.00
    1      xxx   nail      200.00
    1      xxx   labor     200.00
    2     yyy1   chair     150.00
    2     yyy1   table     100.00
    2     yyy2   chain     100.00
    2     yyy2   spring     50.00
```

and the output would be like this

```
    idkey   name   tot_allo  tot_cost
    1        xxx    1000.00    900.00
    2        yyy     500.00    400.00
```

and here's what i've already..

```
SELECT   tableA.name, SUM(tableB.alloted) as tot_allo,
         SUM(tableC.cost) as  tot_cost 
FROM     tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.idkey = tableB.idkey 
            LEFT JOIN tableC ON tableB.idkey = tableC.idkey 
GROUP BY tableA.name
```

and the output of this is not what i've expecting..the tot_allo and tot_cost it doubles its own amount..and why ?

```
table.A.name,    tot_allo,    tot_cost
--------------------------------------
 xxx              2000.00      1800.00
 yyy              1000.00       400.00
```

i would be so glad with any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [joining multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536641/joining-multiple-tables)

Comment: but how ? is there something wrong with my query sir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sub-queries to get the aggregates before joining:

```
select          A.idkey,
                A.name,
                B.tot_allo,
                C.tot_cost
from            tableA A
left outer join (
    select      idkey, sum(alloted) as tot_allo
    from        tableB
    group by    idkey
) B on          B.idkey = A.idkey
left outer join (
    select      idkey, sum(cost) as tot_cost
    from        tableC
    group by    idkey
) C on          C.idkey = A.idkey
```

Using views:

```
create view v_tableB_totals
as
    select      idkey, sum(alloted) as tot_allo
    from        tableB
    group by    idkey

create view v_tableC_totals
as
    select      idkey, sum(cost) as tot_cost
    from        tableC
    group by    idkey

select          A.idkey,
                A.name,
                B.tot_allo,
                C.tot_cost
from            tableA A
left outer join v_tableB_totals B 
    on          B.idkey = A.idkey
left outer join v_tableC_totals C
    on          C.idkey = A.idkey
```

Comment: i'll try this out..tnx btw

Comment: I'd also consider using views or common table expressions for the aggregates, it would make it a bit more readable. Depends on which db you are targetting.

Comment: im not familiar with that views thingy sorry for being noob.. :) but i'll check out with that later..

Comment: You would have to create the views in the db first, then use the select in your sql command

Comment: how to use where clause in views ? like WHERE fieldname = '" & textbox1.text & "'

Comment: exactly the same way you would against a table. select * from v_my_view where foo = 'bar'